# How to create and access a folder structure in .Net core web API after hosting it on Docker

Tags: api, docker, .net-core, microservices

Currently I am using
1. Windows 7
2. Docker Toolbox
3. Visual studio 2017
4. Asp.net core 2.0 Web API

Problem:- First I have created an asp.net core 2.0 web API, which uses a physical path for reading files. It was running perfectly before hosting it to docker.
Then I have enabled support for Docker, build and run the image.
When i try to hit the URL it is giving me exception that "could not find the part of path"

[You can see How I declared a path here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhZ4v.png). Is that right way to do this? Or do I need to make some changes to dockerfile?

Comment: Please provide more details. "How I declared a path here" doesnt lead to anything.

Comment: I have taken the network path like this ->

string _networkPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\TestData\daba";

Comment: and please update your question - past code and error as text, not as an image

Comment: check that your TestData folder exists in docker container, you may forget to publish it. And use `Path.Combine instead` of string concatenation when working with paths. Also, your path has both `/` and `\\` characters,  don't know the OS of your container, but this may be a problem as well

Comment: @Set , yes the path.combine helps if we try to build the images on Linux container also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker toolbox runs on virtual machine but the path I was given is of my windows machine. As I am creating the image on Linux container I also need to map location from where it can get the data file.
It solves the problem when I mapped the app folder while running the container.